# Сниффер на C/C++

Tags: c++, c, сеть, сокет, ip

Мне нужно на своём локальном хосте под Linux анализировать весь входящий траффик на уровне протокола IP и собирать по нему определённую статистику. По сути мне нужен простенький сниффер.

Я прочёл, что сниффер можно организовать, например, через raw socket, открывая его как

```
socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
```

и дальше захватывать пакеты через recvfrom.

Но у меня есть несколько вопросов по этому подходу:

1. Если я захватываю все пакеты через recvfrom, то я их забираю себе из буфера сетевого адаптера и они больше ни к кому не попадут (если я не использую MSG_PEEK)? А если это не так и пакеты остаются для их приёма в других приложениях, то за счёт чего?
2. При открытии сокета я могу использовать IPPROTO_TCP или IPPROTO_UDP или IPPROTO_ICMP. То есть для каждого типа протоколов я должен открывать свой сокет, а если нет и это работает для всех типов одновременно, то зачем это указывать и как указывать правильно?
3. Я правильно понимаю, что указывать IPPROTO_IP не имеет смысла, поскольку это фиктивный протокол и он не будет работать?

А если построить сниффер на библиотеке libpcap, то быстродействие будет выше или ниже? И позволяет ли libpcap не забирать пакеты себе, а считывать их себе для анализа, но при этом и оставлять их для других приложений?

А если требуется обрабатывать очень большую пропускную способность и, соответственно, требуется высокая производительность сниффера, то можно ли его реализовать на библиотеке DPDK и имеет ли это смысл? И если можно, то это накладывает требование использовать DPDK и для приложений для которых предназначен этот траффик? Ведь DPDK захватывает себе адаптер и  через socket с ним уже не получится работать?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Если я захватываю все пакеты через recvfrom, то я их забираю себе из буфера сетевого адаптера и они больше ни к кому не попадут (если я не использую MSG_PEEK)? А если это не так и пакеты остаются для их приёма в других приложениях, то за счёт чего?

Нет, если они предназначены другому приложению, слушающему свой tcp/udp или даже сырой сокет, то они будут доставлены; `MSG_PEEK` не нужен — по идее, с ним будет каждый раз возвращаться один и тот же пакет.

> - А если это не так и пакеты остаются для их приёма в других приложениях, то за счёт чего?

Из сокета `AF_INET` просто получаются все входящие пакеты с указанным протоколом; это ни как не мешает другим приложениям (или tcp-стеку) делать тоже самое.

> 2. При открытии сокета я могу использовать IPPROTO_TCP или IPPROTO_UDP или IPPROTO_ICMP. То есть для каждого типа протоколов я должен открывать свой сокет, а если нет и это работает для всех типов одновременно, то зачем это указывать и как указывать правильно?

Сокеты `AF_INET` в принципе предназначены для реализации в пространстве пользователя конкретных [протоколов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_IP) (они же указанны в заголовке ip-пакета). Так что — да, для каждого протокола нужен отдельный сокет.

> 3. Я правильно понимаю, что указывать IPPROTO_IP не имеет смысла, поскольку это фиктивный протокол и он не будет работать?

Он не «фиктивный», но читать из такого сокета невозможно: он нужен для отправки [почти] произвольных ip-пакетов; так что для описанных выше целей он бесполезен.

---

Собственно, *сырые* сокеты (`AF_INET`/`SOCK_RAW`) — это, скорей всего, не то, что нужно для данной задачи: на них возможно получение только входящих пакетов (получить исходящий трафик или проходящий мимо — невозможно) и только для одного ip-протокола. Для снифинга используются *пакетные* сокеты (домена `AF_PACKET`, [`man 7 packet`](https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=packet&category=7), хотя в разговорной речи их также часто называют «сырыми»).

> А если построить сниффер на библиотеке libpcap, то быстродействие будет выше или ниже?

Под капотом в `pcap` те же самые пакетные сокеты, но взаимодействие с ними идёт через [`PACKET_MMAP`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/packet_mmap.html). Если написать аналогичную реализацию, то производительность будет примерно такой же. Если использовать «наивный вариант» с `recv()` на каждый пакет, то, само собой, производительность будет намного меньше. Но, на сколько я вижу, документация по данному механизму оставляет желать лучшего, так что создать собственную реализацию может быть несколько затруднительно. Если есть возможность использовать `pcap`, то я бы использовал его.

> И позволяет ли libpcap не забирать пакеты себе, а считывать их себе для анализа, но при этом и оставлять их для других приложений?

Если тут ни где нет лишних/недостающих «не», то только так и позволяет. Для противоположной задачи — фильтрации/модификации пакетов нужно писать фильтр/модуль для netilter (возможно и в пользовательском пространстве с помощью [`libnetfilter_queue`](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html)).

---

Про DPDK ничего не скажу — не сталкивался. Но, судя по описанию в данном контексте это звучит как из пушки по муравьям.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Хотел бы ещё уточнить.Мне нужно только анализировать (без какой-либо модификации) только входящий трафик (исходящий мне не нужен) и только на уровне протокола IP. Как я понимаю, AF_PACKET нужен для захвата и входящего и исходящего трафика и вплоть до уровня ETHERNET. Получается для моей задачи он обладает излишними возожностями и мне достаточно AF_INET? Но чтобы анализировать и TCP и UDP мне нужно создавать два сокета с IPPROTO_TCP и с IPPROTO_UDP и вызывать recvfroom на них обоих?

Comment: И если при вызове recvfrom/recv пакеты остаются и для других приложений, то это означает, что по сути у каждого создаваемого сокета своя собственная КОПИЯ очереди пакетов и именно поэтому пакеты доступны для "бесконечного" количества приложений, которые хотят принимать эти данные? Не подскажите, где именнно об этом прочитать?

Comment: @Elija, прошу прощения, что долго не отвечал, хотя добавить по существу мне особо нечего… в принципе, да, если нужны только TCP и UDP, то можно и так сделать (два сокета `AF_INET` и постоянно их слушать), но о какие-либо существенных требованиях к быстродействию тогда придётся забыть… ИМХО предпочтительным способом, если с этим нет проблем, был бы всё же `pcap`…

Comment: И да, у каждого сокета своя очередь пакетов, но как именно пакеты между ними разделяются я доподлинно утверждать не решусь… я бы предположил, что сами пакеты существуют в единственном экземпляре и на них просто подсчитываются ссылки… Что-либо конкретное почитать по теме, как это всё устроено, я тоже не смогу посоветовать… наверное, какой-нибудь талмуд с описанием сетевого стека linux…